# html toggle visibility password inside the input

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html/css, I'm doing a registration form and I'd like to put the eye toggle to show the password inside the password input field, there is a way to do it to keep the scalability in the different resolutions? Searching online I think that I have to put them in a container and then use css but if I try to do it changing the container in css the whole my form breaks...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index Registration</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-9">
                    <div class="login-wrap py-3 px-4">
                        <h2 style="color: #FFF; text-align: center;" class="text-uppercase text-center mb-5">Create new Account</h2>
                        <form class="form-sigin" action="../home/index.php" name="formRegistration" id="formRegistration"  method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="firstNameNewUser" style="margin-left: 0px;">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name ="firstNameNewUser" id="firstNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="form-label" for="lastNameNewUser">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name ="lastNameNewUser" id="lastNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control mb-4">
                                <label class="form-label" for="nickNewUser">Your Nickname</label>
                                <input type="text" name ="nickNewUser" id="nickNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control mb-4">
                                <label class="form-label" for="emailNewUser">Your Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name ="emailNewUser" id="emailNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control mb-4">
                                <label class="form-label" for="passwordNewUser">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name ="passwordNewUser" id="passwordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                <i> <span class="material-icons">visibility</span> </i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control mb-4">
                                <label class="form-label" for="rPasswordNewUser">Repeat your password</label>
                                <div class="parent inline-flex-parent">
                                    <div class="child">
                                        <input type="password" name ="rPasswordNewUser" id="rPasswordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="child">
                                        <i> <span class="material-icons">visibility</span> </i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check" id="form-checkbox">
                                <input
                                    class="form-check-input me-2"
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value=""
                                    name="checkboxterms"
                                    id="checkboxterms"
                                />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxterms" name="checkboxtermslabel" id="checkboxtermslabel">
                                    I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            
                            <p id="spacing">&nbsp;</p> 

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                <button type="submit" id = "registerButton" name="registerButton" class="btn btn-primary rounded submit p-2 px-4">Register</button>
                            </div>
                            
                            <p class="text-center text-muted mt-5 mb-0">Have already an account? 
                                <a href="../login/index.php" class="text-white"><u>Login here</u></a>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

EDIT:
the current password code you see are just some tests that I'm doing, If I don't put the passw input field and the  inside a div, then they will be put one over the other, so I created a div to put them side by side... by also like this, if the resolution change then the eye icon will not be in the right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I implement pw visibility. As far as scalability, if you use Bootstrap's sizing classes it should all scale well.  I've had no issues moving this between assorted screen sizes.

### Addendum : centering the Eye

I modified the second password field.
To properly vertically center it I had to alter the html. Compare against the first password HTML.

In particular:

1. wrapped the "eye" containing div and the input in it's own `relative` div. (`position-relative` moved from outer `div.control`
2. Added Bootstrap class `h-100` to the "eye" `div`
3. Added bootstrap class `align-middle` to the "eye" and
4. Created an actual rule for .pw-toggle that sets `height: 1rem;` so that `align-middle` centers correctly.

```js
$(function() {
  $("span.pw-toggle, span.pw-toggle2").click(function() {
    var $pwField = $($(this).data().target);
    var TorP = $pwField.attr('type') == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    $(this).text(TorP === "password" ? "visibility" : "visibility_off")
    $pwField.attr('type', TorP);
  });
});
```

```css
span[data-target] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pw-toggle {
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-9">
          <div class="login-wrap py-3 px-4">
            <h2 style="color: #FFF; text-align: center;" class="text-uppercase text-center mb-5">Create new Account</h2>
            <form class="form-sigin" action="../home/index.php" name="formRegistration" id="formRegistration" method="post">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="firstNameNewUser" style="margin-left: 0px;">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstNameNewUser" id="firstNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="lastNameNewUser">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastNameNewUser" id="lastNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="control mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="nickNewUser">Your Nickname</label>
                <input type="text" name="nickNewUser" id="nickNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
              </div>

              <div class="control mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="emailNewUser">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="emailNewUser" id="emailNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
              </div>

              <div class="control mb-4 position-relative">
                <label class="form-label" for="passwordNewUser">Password</label>
                <div class="position-absolute end-0 me-1">
                  <span data-target="#passwordNewUser" class="pw-toggle material-icons pr-1">visibility</span>
                </div>
                <input type="password" name="passwordNewUser" id="passwordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
              </div>

              <div class="control mb-4">
                <label class="form-label" for="rPasswordNewUser">Repeat your password</label>
                <div class="position-relative">
                  <div class="position-absolute end-0 me-1 h-100">
                    <span data-target="#rPasswordNewUser" class="pw-toggle material-icons pr-1 align-middle">visibility</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="password" name="rPasswordNewUser" id="rPasswordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Just for fun, the eye as a Bootstrap input 
              addon is much cleaner -->

              <div clas="control mb-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="password" name="r2PasswordNewUser" id="r2PasswordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                  <span data-target="#r2PasswordNewUser" class="pw-toggle2 material-icons">visibility</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-check" id="form-checkbox">
                <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" name="checkboxterms" id="checkboxterms" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxterms" name="checkboxtermslabel" id="checkboxtermslabel">
                                    I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                                </label>
              </div>

              <p id="spacing">&nbsp;</p>

              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <button type="submit" id="registerButton" name="registerButton" class="btn btn-primary rounded submit p-2 px-4">Register</button>
              </div>

              <p class="text-center text-muted mt-5 mb-0">Have already an account?
                <a href="../login/index.php" class="text-white"><u>Login here</u></a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, just one question:
the eye icon it's in the middle(vertically) of the input field, how can I center it?

Comment: I tried to put the span's div and the input field inside another div and in the style use vertical-aling:middle for the span's div but it didn't work

Comment: good start, but you need to do some tweaking. see addendum for how I centered the second PW input

Comment: also maybe consider moving the eye to a Bootstrap input addon.

Comment: I just added the eye as a bootstrap input addon for the fun of it.  It's actually much cleaner html.

Comment: Searching input addon I found input group, and the lnly group that could help me it's with the button I think, but I should replace the button with the icon eye, I don't know if you mean this

Comment: sorry, I used the nomenclature from BS3, old habits die hard, but yes, that's it. I put an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would implement that functionality with JavaScript. We grab the eye ball icon and the two password fields. Then, loop through the eyeBall and add an event listener to it. It checks whether the type attribute is password or text. If it is password, it changes it to text.

```js
            let eyeBall = document.getElementsByClassName('viewPass');
            let passInput = document.getElementsByClassName('passwordInput');
            let passField = document.getElementById('passwordNewUser');


            function change_visibility($type) {
                for(let field of passInput) {
                    field.setAttribute('type', $type);
                }
            }

            for(let eye of eyeBall) {
                eye.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    if (passField.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
                        change_visibility('text');
                    } else {
                        change_visibility('password');
                    }

                });
            }
```

```css
.viewPass {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Index Registration</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-9">
                        <div class="login-wrap py-3 px-4">
                            <h2 style="color: #FFF; text-align: center;" class="text-uppercase text-center mb-5">Create new Account</h2>
                            <form class="form-sigin" action="../home/index.php" name="formRegistration" id="formRegistration"  method="post">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="firstNameNewUser" style="margin-left: 0px;">First Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name ="firstNameNewUser" id="firstNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="lastNameNewUser">Last Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name ="lastNameNewUser" id="lastNameNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="nickNewUser">Your Nickname</label>
                                    <input type="text" name ="nickNewUser" id="nickNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="emailNewUser">Your Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name ="emailNewUser" id="emailNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="passwordNewUser">Password</label>
                                    <input class="passwordInput" type="password" name ="passwordNewUser" id="passwordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                    <i class="viewPass"> <span class="material-icons">visibility</span> </i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label" for="rPasswordNewUser">Repeat your password</label>
                                    <div class="parent inline-flex-parent">
                                        <div class="child">
                                            <input class="passwordInput" type="password" name ="rPasswordNewUser" id="rPasswordNewUser" size="40" maxlength="40" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="child">
                                            <i class="viewPass"> <span class="material-icons">visibility</span> </i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-check" id="form-checkbox">
                                    <input
                                        class="form-check-input me-2"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        value=""
                                        name="checkboxterms"
                                        id="checkboxterms"
                                    />
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checkboxterms" name="checkboxtermslabel" id="checkboxtermslabel">
                                        I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                
                                <p id="spacing">&nbsp;</p> 

                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                    <button type="submit" id = "registerButton" name="registerButton" class="btn btn-primary rounded submit p-2 px-4">Register</button>
                                </div>
                                
                                <p class="text-center text-muted mt-5 mb-0">Have already an account? 
                                    <a href="../login/index.php" class="text-white"><u>Login here</u></a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```